# When converting string to integer from txt file, I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

I am trying to create an external highscore file.

```
highscoreFile = open("highscore.txt", "r+")
highscore = highscoreFile.read()

if current > int(highscore):
    highscoreFile.truncate(0)
    print(highscore)
```

It works if highscore.txt has only a 0, but if it is any number I get the error. If I check the value of highscore right before the if statement (using pycharm debug), it gives me a string value of what the high score is, which is what I would expect. Though, whent trying to print it, says it is nonetype. Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: the error indicates that the string you are trying to convert to an integer does **not** consist only of the characters `[0-9]`. what's the full content of your `highscore.txt` file?

Comment: I see now that there was a space before the number for some reason

Comment: Your code works fine if the file contains a number, even with a leading space. If run twice, though, it fails with the error you got, because the file is empty (due to `highscoreFile.truncate(0)`).

Comment: It's always good to sanitize your inputs if its not to costly. I would try `highscore = highscoreFile.read().strip()` to remove any leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score -2):

For some reason the script created spaces before the number in the file.

Comment: Nothing in your code is writing to a file, and your code already handles a leading space with no issues, so how is this the answer?

Comment: `int("  3")` returns `3`, so that's not a problem.